# Unity EventSystem

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я использую один код для карточек, что снизу -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ChooseCard : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, 
IPointerUpHandler
{
GameObject moveCard;
Slot slot;
GameObject book;
int id;

void Start()
{
    moveCard = GameObject.Find("SlotMouseCard");
    moveCard.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
    slot = GetComponent<Slot>();
    book = GameObject.Find("Book");
}

public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData eventData) 
{
    if(slot.card != null)
    {
        moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card = slot.card;
        id = slot.card.id;
        slot.card = null;
        moveCard.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public void OnPointerUp (PointerEventData eventData) 
{
    moveCard.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
    if(slot.card == null)
    {
        slot.card = moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card;
        moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card = null;
    }
    else if(slot.card != null)
    {
        book.GetComponent<Book>().collection[id] = null;
    }
    id = -1;
    moveCard.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

И другой код для карточек сверху -

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CardOfCollaction : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
GameObject moveCard;
Slot slot;
void Start()
{
    moveCard = GameObject.Find("SlotMouseCard");
    slot = GetComponent<Slot>();
}

public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData) 
{
    if(moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card != null)
    {
        slot.card = moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card;
        moveCard.GetComponent<Slot>().card = null;
    }
}
}
```

И вот что выходит - [image: Перетаскивание карт]
Как мне пeредать значение верхним картам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventSystem работает по принципу первого столкновения луча. Т.е. из камеры бросается луч, который сталкивается с объектом, после чего у этого объекта ищутся интерфейсы системы.

У вас на сцене есть объект EventSystem, если вы его выберете и раскроете окно внизу инспектора, то увидите все текущие значения из него - на что наведён ваш курсор, на что произошёл последний клик и т.д.

Могу предположить, что если вы это сделаете, то увидите, что всё время перетаскивания ваш курсор наведён на перетаскиваемую карту. Другими словами - карта вверху не узнает, что курсор в неё вошёл, потому что курсор в неё не входит - он всё время находится внутри перетягиваемой карты, т.к. луч системы всегда упирается в неё.

Судя по всему, карты сделаны через элемент UI - Image. У этого компонента есть буловая переменная - `RaycastTarget`. Она отвечает за то, может ли луч столкнуться с этим объектом. Отключите её у объекта - перетаскиваемой карты. Скорее всего это решит проблему.

Так же, в качестве совета. Для перетаскивания существуют интерфейсы:
`IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler`, `IEndDragHandler` - для объекта, который перетаскиваете. Для работы необходимо обязательно реализовывать `IDragHandler`
`IDropHandler` - для объекта, на который вы бросаете перетаскиваемый.
А из аргумента методов `PointerEventData eventData` можно получить текущий перетаскиваемый объект, который хранится в `eventData.pointerDrag`. На момент срабатывания метода `IDropHandler` объект всё ещё будет там.